# Inconsistent result from calculating the speed of a jumping dog relative to its boat

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum

Consider a problem as follows.

> A dog with a mass of 5 kg is at rest on a moving boat with mass of 20 kg. The speed of the boat is 1 m/s (relative to the ground).
>   If the dog leaves the boat by jumping at the speed of 2 m/s (relative to the boat) in the direction of the boat moves, find the speed of the boat (relative to the ground) after this event? Ignore any possible frictional forces.

I am not sure that my calculation below is correct. I take the ground as the frame of reference.

## Before Jumping

Before jumping both dog and boat have the same speed relative to the ground, i.e., 1 m/s. So momentum of the system before jumping is

\begin{align}
p &=m_dv_d+m_bv_b \\
 &=5\times1+20\times1=25\\
\end{align}

## After Jumping

When the dog jumps at speed 2 m/s relative to the boat, the boat moves at speed $v_b'$ relative to the ground. It means the dog jump at speed $v_d'=2+v_b'$ relative to the ground.

Momentum of the system after jumping is
\begin{align}
p' &=m_dv_d'+m_bv_b'\\
&=5\times(2+v_b')+20\times v_b'\\
&=10+25v_b'
\end{align}

Applying the law of conservation, I have

\begin{align}
p&=p'\\
25&=10+25v_b'\\
v_b'&=0.6
\end{align}

But according to the answer key, $v_b'=1/2$ m/s.

## Questions

Which is the correct answer? mine or the answer key?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

velocity of dog after jumping from the boat is *3m/s*, since it already had a velocity of *1m/s* and another *2m/s* relative to the boat. Change the expression of velocity of dog wrt ground as $v_{dg}=v_{db}+v_{bg}$ (*velocity of dog wrt ground= velocity of dog wrt boat+velocity of boat wrt ground*)

*Initial momentum = final momentum in the direction in which there is no force....*

$(5+20)$*($1m/s$) = $5$*($3m/s$) + $20$*($x$ $m/s$)

Comment: Please write the complete equation.

Comment: After jumping, the boat speed changes to $x$ so the dog speed relative to the ground become $2+x$ rather than 3, right?

Comment: the dog did not jump with $2m/s$ relative to the boat when the boat's speed was $x$, it jumped when the boat's speed was $1$. so it is $2 + 1$

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is wrong as ,if you are performing all calculations w.r.t. ground then you also need to take the velocity of dog w.r.t. ground which would be 3m/s as the boat is already moving with a velocity of 1m/s w.r.t. ground and dog has jumped from the boat with velocity 2m/s w.r.t. the boat therefore the velocity of dog w.r.t. ground will be 3m/s , if you take this value in your calculations then you will get the velocity of boat as 1/2 m/s .